# Replication Data Issue

Tags: sql-server, database-replication

After configuring replication all the data from tables has replicated from publisher to subscriber. Now my requirement is whenever I insert new record in publisher only that record should replicate rather than reinitialize all the records to subscriber because my table is having millions of records.

Rather than drop and reinitialize snapshot cont we store earlier sync data of table in subscriber and only sync the new record.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: what you are asking for can be achieved using [Merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152746.aspx) or [Transactional Replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176.aspx).

Comment: Transaction Rep we are using

Comment: Publisher table -- almost 1 million records. Subscriber -- 1 million plus whenever I insert new record into publisher generally it will drop the table in subscriber and create with 1 million plus 1 new record.. So getting latency to get the records in subscriber... I need to make old 1 million records are fixed and new record only has to insert into subscriber table... Is it possible?

Comment: How did you initialise the subscriber? manually?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using transactional replication (as you say above in your comments), something is configured incorrectly. Transactional replication is supposed to work as you describe (i.e. a one row change gets pushed over and applied as a one row change). I'd guess that you have the immediate_sync property turned on at the publisher and are running the snapshot agent on a schedule. At the very least, turn off the schedule for the snapshot agent and I think you'll see your problem go away.

Comment: I was configured proper only.. I am asking is there any possibility to fix already replicated records rather than replicating every time

Comment: If your replication setup is behaving as you describe (i.e. one row changing → a full re-init of the table), that is most certainly not properly configured.